# Adding a column by reference to every data.table in a list does not "stick"

Tags: r

I have a list of many metering data.tables each with a UTC timestamp column (all the other columns are unit meterings). I want to add a CET column by reference to each of the data.tables. Weirdly this does not seem to stick.

My code:

```
lapply(list_dtmetering, function(x) x[, cet:=utc  + hours(1)])
```

When I run this, I get each element printed out to the console, showing the added column. Then when I do ...

```
names(list_dtmetering[[1]])
```

...I only get the original column names. The "cet" column is gone!

I tried a simpler example to check my syntax but this show the expected behaviour:

```
> c1 = 1:5
> DT = data.table(c1)
> L = list(DT)
> L
[[1]]
   c1
1:  1
2:  2
3:  3
4:  4
5:  5

> lapply(L, function(x) x[, C2:=c1+10])
[[1]]

> L
[[1]]
   c1 C2
1:  1 11
2:  2 12
3:  3 13
4:  4 14
5:  5 15
```

Does anybody know why this does not work in my first example?
list_dtmetering is only 900Mb.

Comment: In case all your data.tables in `list_dtmetering` have the same structure (order, type, and names of columns) have you considered to `rbindlist(list_dtmetering, idcol = TRUE)` into a one large data.table?

Comment: Thanks for you reply, as a workaround I've indeed created one large data.table (using rbindlist & merge by "utc"), then I've modified the "utc" into a "cet" column. However, I would very much like to know why my previous syntax didn't work.